# How to display left,right and bottom border 100% and top border 40%

Tags: html, css, border

I have a box with a border along with text inside it. Now I have to display the only half top border something like the below image. How can  I achieve this? I tried after and before class but now how can I display the left and right border?

[image]

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.heroContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.heroContent:before,
.heroContent:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f4d03f;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px
}

.heroContent:after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.heroContent:before {
  top: 0;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heroContent">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your approach using :before and :after for the top and bottom. Since you only needed the top border to be shorter, you could have just had that as the pseudo element, and used a `border-bottom` for the bottom border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the 3 other borders using a standard border. Create the top border with a pseudo-element (`:before`):

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.heroContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  border-color: #f4d03f;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.heroContent:before {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: -1px;
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f4d03f;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px
}
```

```html
<div class="heroContent">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h2>
</div>
```

Another option is to create the partial borders using linear gradients as background:

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.heroContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  border-color: #f4d03f;
  border-width: 0 0 3px 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, #f4d03f 40%, transparent 40%) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 60%, #f4d03f 60%) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 3px, 3px 100%;
  background-position: top left, top right;
}
```

```html
<div class="heroContent">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I need small help if I have to display the top 40% and right border 40% then? do I need to use : after for the right border?

Comment: Use linear gradients for both (see 2nd example)

Comment: but linear gradients changing only the top border. I

Comment: I've updated the example to include the right as well.

Comment: Yes, both answer is working for me. Let me understand your answer. give me 5 mins

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and upvote for the second option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the `heroContent` class a `border-left` and a `border-right`.

Like so:

```
border-left: 3px solid #f4d03f;
border-right: 3px solid #f4d03f;
```

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.heroContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  border-left: 3px solid #f4d03f;
  border-right: 3px solid #f4d03f;
}

.heroContent:before,
.heroContent:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f4d03f;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px
}

.heroContent:after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.heroContent:before {
  top: 0;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heroContent">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: One small help if I have to display the right border 40% than what I have to change it?

Comment: I mean the top 40% and right border 40%

Comment: Thanks for the help and your answer is also working for me. upvote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add:

```
.heroContent {
  border-left: solid 3px #f4d03f;
  border-right: solid 3px #f4d03f;
}
```

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z24rksvc/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
        width: 500px;
        /* height: 100px; */
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 20px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        border: 1px solid red;
          border-top: none;
          padding:10px;
    }

 div::before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 30%;
        left: 0%;
         
        border-top: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<div>
Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Donec sed odio dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.

Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add  to h2

```
h2{    
  border: 3px solid #f4d03f;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 3px solid #f4d03f;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.heroContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.heroContent:before,
.heroContent:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #f4d03f;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px
}

.heroContent:after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.heroContent:before {
  top: 0;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="heroContent">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h2>
</div>
```